# Why does my touchpad stop working when I plug in my (normal, non-USB) headphones?

Tags: output, touchpad, input, xinput, chrome-book

It's the darnedest thing. And only started happening within the last two days. Whenever I plug in my 3.5mm AKG headphones into the appropriate spot on my Acer Chromebook 15 CB3-532 running Ubuntu 18, either right away or after a few minutes, the touchpad stops responding. The computer itself is not frozen, as keyboard commands work just fine, and it isn't a hardware problem because I'm dual-booting with crouton and when I boot into Chrome OS, it doesn't happen.

I've reinstalled xserver-xorg-input-[libinput, wacom, all, but not cmt.] but to no avail.

I'm at a loss. I cannot even begin to guess how to start diagnosing this one, so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[Small update: I've realized this (the touchpad freezing) only happens when the laptop is already on and I plug the headphones in and pulseaudio autodetects which port to change to. If I plug the headphones in while the laptop is still off and then manually change the port, the touchpad is fine. So weird. ]

Update:
Here's the output for `tail -f /var/log/kern.log`

> Aug 16 19:29:39 poutingcavity kernel: [ 37.985793] wlp2s0: send auth
>   to 5c:6a:80:1c:ce:21 (try 1/3)
>
> Aug 16 19:29:39 poutingcavity kernel: [ 37.990154] wlp2s0:
>   authenticated
>
> Aug 16 19:29:39 poutingcavity kernel: [ 37.992492] wlp2s0: associate
>   with 5c:6a:80:1c:ce:21 (try 1/3)
>
> Aug 16 19:29:40 poutingcavity kernel: [ 37.998643] wlp2s0: RX
>   AssocResp from 5c:6a:80:1c:ce:21 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=3)
>
> Aug 16 19:29:40 poutingcavity kernel: [ 38.009496] wlp2s0: associated
>
> Aug 16 19:29:40 poutingcavity kernel: [ 38.107098] IPv6:
>   ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
>
> Aug 16 19:29:43 poutingcavity kernel: [ 41.345344] intel_sst_acpi
>   808622A8:00: FW Version 01.0b.02.02
>
> Aug 16 19:29:44 poutingcavity kernel: [ 42.950287] Bluetooth: RFCOMM
>   TTY layer initialized
>
> Aug 16 19:29:44 poutingcavity kernel: [ 42.950300] Bluetooth: RFCOMM
>   socket layer initialized
>
> Aug 16 19:29:44 poutingcavity kernel: [ 42.950317] Bluetooth: RFCOMM
>   ver 1.11

It doesn't change whether my headphones are plugged in or not.

And here's the output for `dmesg | grep -i error`

> [ 1.644497] pwm-lpss: probe of 80862288:00 failed with error -16
>
> [ 1.946133] tpm_tis: probe of 00:07 failed with error -16
>
> [ 4.541133] RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
>
> [ 6.348804] cros_ec_lpcs: probe of GOOG0004:00 failed with error -2
>
> [ 6.638066] i915 0000:00:02.0: Disabling error capture for VT-d
>   workaround

Comment: Can you post the output of dmesg upon headphone connection?

Comment: Sorry, dumb question, but is there a particular dmesg command that I can parse to make it less verbose and maybe more specific? Otherwise pasting the whole thing  here exceeds the character limit.

Comment: tail -f /var/log/dmesg | grep USB

Comment: How come USB? These are not USB headphones. They're going straight into the headphone jack.

Comment: So drop the grep Part. Let's see what happens when you Plug it

Comment: Here's the output for  tail -f /var/log/dmesg :P --
'tail: cannot open '/var/log/dmesg' for reading: No such file or directory
tail: no files remaining'